# bundle.js shows HTML code instead of javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying to set up redux server side rendering using express.js. I am almost done with the set up hpwever, i am seeing the below error when express renders the page on browser

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in `bundle.js` file. I figured out that in source tab, `bundle.js` is having HTML code instead of my webpack built compiled js code. I think this is the issue which is causing the error.

Below are the files that would help to find out where I am going wrong

[image: Project structure]

server **index.js**

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import config from '../webpack.config.js';
import open from 'open';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import handleRender from '../client/src/utils/handleRender.js';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

webpack(config).run((err, results) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(handleRender);

// Trigger server
app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(chalk.red("Whoa!!! Server crashed..."), err);
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.green("YAY!!! Server is up and running..."));
    // open(`http://localhost:${port}/home`);
  }
});
```

**renderFullPage.js**

```
'use strict';

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>
        <script type=text/javascript src="../../../build/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}

export default renderFullPage;
```

**handleRender.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import renderFullPage from './renderFullPage.js';
import App from '../containers/App.js';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const handleRender = (req, res) => {
  // Create a new Redux store instance
  const store = createStore(rootReducer);

  // Render the component to a string
  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
  const preloadedState = store.getState();

  // Send the rendered page back to the client
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
}

export default handleRender;
```

Please let me know if any other information is required on the same. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exposing your bundle files to the browser. Your script src `../../../build/bundle.js` won't work - that file is on that path only on your local machine, not on the server.

In your server index.js file you need to set your build directory as a static resource for express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './build'), { maxAge: 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 }));
```

And then update your script's src: `<script type=text/javascript src="/bundle.js"></script>`